# Replace the keys of one dictionary with the values from another IF the keys of both dictionaries match

Tags: python, dictionary

I have two dictionaries.

```
a = {3: 1, 14: 2, 4: 3, 1: 4, 5: 5, 16: 6, 2: 7, 6: 8, 15: 9, 10: 10, 7: 11, 9: 12, 8: 13, 12: 14, 13: 15, 11: 16} 
b = {1: 29, 2: 63, 3: 29, 4: 32, 5: 46, 6: 29, 7: 24, 8: 63, 9: 67, 10: 46, 11: 29, 12: 24, 13: 67, 14: 2, 15: 63, 16: 2, 17: 42}
```

I want to assign the values of a to the values of b if the keys match. Or some other similar result. I've been learning Python for about a week and I'm pretty sure the answer involves list comprehension but I just can't get my ahead around some of the other answers on here so a step by step for loop style answer would be much appreciated. Thanks

EDIT.
Sorry for not showing previous efforts. I was trying something like this (as one of the comments suggested) but I don't understand why it doesn't return what I need.

```
for k1, v1 in a.items():
        for k2, v2 in b.items():
            if(k1 == k2):
                b[k2] = v1
```

Also this:

```
for k1,v1 in a.items():
        for k2,v2 in b.items():
            if k1 in b.items():
                b[k2] = a[v1]
```

For clarity, I've updated the dictionaries to have strings for keys.

```
a = {'2': 1, '3': 2, '4': 3, '5': 4, '1': 5, '6': 6, '7': 7, '8': 8, '9': 9, '10': 10, '11': 11, '12': 12, '13': 13, '14': 14, '15': 15, '16': 16}
b = {'1': 67, '2': 46, '3': 32, '4': 63, '5': 49, '6': 63, '7': 67, '8': 67, '9': 2, '10': 2, '11': 24, '12': 67, '13': 49, '14': 67, '15': 63, '16': 46, '17': 42}
```

I want to replace the strings in b with the integers from a (and do nothing if strings don't match) ie. no strings in the result. The strings are for associating values. As far as I can tell (not far) and unless I'm mistaken (very likely), most answers provided so far don't do this - they seem to think I want to replace v2 with v1, not k2 with v1. Apologies if that's wrong. The order of dictionary **a** can be jumbled as well which I tried to represent in my first example but for the second example I've only displaced key "1". In any case, the desired output from example two is:

```
new dict = {5: 67, 1: 46, 2: 32, 3: 63, 4: 49, 6: 63... 16: 46}
```

Hope that makes sense. Any further help greatly appreciated. Apologies again for noobishness.

EDIT2: A SOLUTION

Got what I needed from this:

```
new_dict = {}
    for k1, v1 in a.items():
        for k2, v2 in b.items():
            if k1 == k2:
                new_dict[v1] = v2
```

I'm sure there's fat to be trimmed - critiques welcome. Sorry if this question is now shit show - happy to hear edit suggestions.

Comment: please add what you have tried to your post ... perhaps a link to the answer that you do not understand

Comment: It might be better for you if you post your own effort first and have people comment on / improve it.

Comment: In English that might read: for every key in b, set the value to the corresponding value in a if it exists, otherwise just use the value from b. In python that sounds like a dict comprehension: `{k:a[k] if k in a else v for k, v in b.items()} `

Comment: So if there's any difference in keys, you want to do nothing?

Comment: @Mark Rather sounds like a job for `get`.

Comment: Yeah, @KellyBundy that might be less verbose. For the OP, this looks like: `{k:a.get(k, v) for k, v in b.items()}` because `get()` allows a default when the key is not found in the dictionary.

Comment: @Mark Now that I see it... `{k:a.get(*i) for i in b.items()}`.

Comment: In your example, the keys *don't* match. So nothing should be done? Otherwise please show the expected result.

Comment: *"I'm pretty sure the answer involves list comprehension"*- Why? You don't have or want any lists, do you?

Answer (score 2):

Iterate over the set of keys in **a** and if that key exists in **b**, set **b**'s value at that key to the value of **a** at that key

```
for key in a.keys():
    if key in b:
      b[key] = a[key]
```

Hope it helped

Comment: Thanks. I'm looking to make b[key] = a[value] though..?

Comment: So you want b[key] = a[b[key]]?
In that case you should see if b[key] in a:
and then do the assignment

Answer (score 0):

You can loop the dict ***a***.

Add a condition if ***a*** key exist in dict ***b***

If they match, assign the dict ***b*** with key as the value from the dict ***a***

```
for _a in a:
    if _a in b:
        b[_a] = a[_a]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
a = {3: 1, 14: 2, 4: 3, 1: 4, 5: 5, 16: 6, 2: 7, 6: 8, 15: 9, 10: 10, 7: 11, 9: 12, 8: 13, 12: 14, 13: 15, 11: 16} 
b = {1: 29, 2: 63, 3: 29, 4: 32, 5: 46, 6: 29, 7: 24, 8: 63, 9: 67, 10: 46, 11: 29, 12: 24, 13: 67, 14: 2, 15: 63, 16: 2, 17: 42}

a_list = list(a)
b_list = list(b)
for key in range(len(a_list)):
    if b_list[key] == a_list[key]:
        b[b_list[key]] = a[a_list[key]]


print(b)
```

outputs `{1: 29, 2: 63, 3: 29, 4: 32, 5: 5, 6: 29, 7: 24, 8: 63, 9: 67, 10: 10, 11: 29, 12: 24, 13: 67, 14: 2, 15: 63, 16: 2, 17: 42}`

not sure if this is the output you wanted

Answer (score -1):

```
a = {3: 1, 14: 2, 4: 3, 1: 4, 5: 5, 16: 6, 2: 7, 6: 8, 15: 9, 10: 10, 7: 11, 9: 12, 8: 13, 12: 14, 13: 15, 11: 16} 
b = {1: 29, 2: 63, 3: 29, 4: 32, 5: 46, 6: 29, 7: 24, 8: 63, 9: 67, 10: 46, 11: 29, 12: 24, 13: 67, 14: 2, 15: 63, 16: 2, 17: 42}

for key_a, value_a in a.items():
    for key_b, value_b in b.items():
        if(key_a == key_b):
            b[key_b] = value_a
print(b)
```

**Edit:** Or more efficiently, as recommended by @Mark (and done by @marcusoft):

```
for key in a.keys():
    if key in b.keys():
        b[key] = a[key]
print(b)
```

**Output:**

```
{1: 4, 2: 7, 3: 1, 4: 3, 5: 5, 6: 8, 7: 11, 8: 13, 9: 12, 10: 10, 11: 16, 12: 14, 13: 15, 14: 2, 15: 9, 16: 6, 17: 42}
```

Comment: There is *no reason* to loop through keys in both dictionaries. This makes a simple linear routine quadratic in complexity.

Comment: Thanks, you are right. Already updated the answer